# How does joda datetimeformat impact the simpledateformat

Tags: java, multithreading, jodatime

As we know, simpleDateFormat are not thread-safe. When facing multi-thread, simpleDateFormat may throw some exceptions. So, I decided to use joda-time instead.

However, when I use joda-time together with simpleDateFormat, some thing strange happened.

#### Expect result:

simpleDateFormat throws exception, joda-time parsed successfully.

#### Actual result:

both parsed successfully.

Look at the code I wrote for test below.

```
public class MultiThreadDateTest {

  private static SimpleDateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  private static DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
  private static final int THREAD_SIZE = 4;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_SIZE; i++) {
      new Thread(new JavaDateThread()).start();
      new Thread(new JodaDateThread()).start();
    }
  }

  private static class JavaDateThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        Date date = dformat.parse("1999-01-01");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": " + date);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  private static class JodaDateThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      Date date = format.parseDateTime("2000-01-01").toDate();
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": " + date);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just because it didn't throw an exception doesn't mean it's safe to do. More likely, if you use it in a situation where you're parsing lots of *different* strings (instead of the same string repeatedly) you'd end up with some dates which contained mixtures of different inputs.

Comment: @Jon Skeet You are right. I tried to change the string with constructor and  the execution order of threads. Some exception throws as expected. I guess the reason is because joda-time occupied the CPU and simpleDateFormat doesn't have time to modify others' instance.

Comment: @Jon Skeet thanks for your comment :)

Comment: I'm concerned that you're still focusing on exceptions though. It would be perfectly possible for `SimpleDateFormat` to be misbehaving when used from multiple threads without throwing exceptions. You mustn't treat a lack of exceptions as a sign that nothing's wrong.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Yeah, I understood, you mean "2000-01-01" and "2001-01-01" may parsed successfully but incorrectly. Anyway, thanks for the reminder.